# Spring boot: query definition using JPQL

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am new to Spring boot and hibernate. Here I am trying run a search based parameter query, where i want to search by sex. If I kept this field null then query should list all items. But the problem is my method is returning all data ignoring my search parameter. My service class looks like:

```
public interface HouseholdService {

    @Query(value = "select * from household where sex = 1", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Women> getEligibleWomen();

}
```

My Impl looks like

```
@Service
public class HouseholdImpl implements HouseholdService {

    @Autowired
    private HouseholdRepository householdRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Women> getEligibleWomen() {
        return householdRepository.findBy();
    }
```

My Repository interface looks like

```
public interface HouseholdRepository extends CrudRepository<Women, String>
{
  
     List<Women> findBy();
}
```

Can Any one help me in this regard? please?

Comment: Obviously an `@Query` on an interface that isn't going to be processed by Spring Data is not going to work. That method should be on the `HouseholdRepository` not the service or at least the`@Query` should be.

Comment: Daaaamn, silly me, thank you, it worked